# Angular : How many modules are abit too many when it comes to Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Lets say I am building an Application which somehow was designed to have like 100(hypothetically) features and I plan to put them Separately into their respective `FeatureModules` which may or may not be interdependent on each other while exporting some of its functionality.

Are there any best practices of how we should manage these many modules in the code from Angular's perspective ?

Would the number of Modules be a factor in the Application's performance if we exempt the load time of the code ?